# Slice to index or end, if end is lesser then index (python)

Tags: python, slice

I would like to get slice for some `np.ndarray` object `foo`:

```
bar = foo[:end]
```

But sometimes end can be greater than `len(foo)`. Then I would like to get `bar = foo`. I can reach this, if I write `bar = foo[:min(end, len(foo)]`. But it seems not pythonic. Is there simpler way to do this?

Comment: If `foo` is a Python list with a length less than `end`, then `foo[:end]` returns a copy of `foo`. Do `np.ndarray` objects not do this? What behavior do they exhibit when sliced this way?

Comment: I agree with @CoryKramer here. It's short and clear.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour when `end` is greater than the length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't need any special logic to handle slicing out of range. By default if `end` is too large, the slice will include the end of the array.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a = a[:10]
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
```